# WCF service with dll as a model

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, design-patterns

I have WCF (TCP) Service that expose only code contract (without mex).
I have a model dll that defines several classes like Person and product.

Both the client side (Silverlight/WPF) work with this model.

I have to bind the instance class to some binding elements in the client application.

But as you know there are several interfaces that we have to implement on the model class like `INotifyPropertyChanged` for example.

So how do I implement them on the model class which came from dll, should I use the adapter pattern to do so? but if I do I have no way to get to the set property of the fields in that class.

That is to say, inheriting from the user class for example and implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider them as **models**, they shouldn't have `INotifyPropertyChanged` on them. You'd want a **ViewModel** to have that, thus being an MVVM application. MVVM was designed to make use of the binding functions of WPF, and to create a clear separation between your UI and business layers.

You need to create view models that implement all the `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff you want for your UI, and they will interact with the model classes you have in your .dll.

If you are not familiar with MVVM, here is a few helpful links:

- [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)
- [Explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much it certainly helps.